# JWT token - Passcode for private key

Tags: rsa, jwt, private-key

I am trying to build a JWT token using an online JWT generator located at http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html

I understand how a JWT is put together but one thing that is confusing me is a field the form asks for termed a "**passcode for private key**". I understand what a private key is, however, I am not familiar with a passcode for a private key.

Does anyone know what this is referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PKCS#8 private key can be encrypted with a password using a DES3 or AES symmetric encryption algorithm

The online generator is asking you for a key like this and the corresponding password

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: I was not aware that a private key was sometimes encrypted. What algorithm is used to encrypt the private key?

Comment: Usually AES or DES3. It is described in pkcs#5. You can see also the documentation of openssl conversion tool https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/pkcs8.html